# When changeset cast, how to set permitted fields by all fields?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

My code is as follows:

```
  defp import_product(importer, head, product) do
    IO.inspect("import_product")
    head_a = Enum.map(Enum.slice(head, 0, 10), &String.to_existing_atom/1)
    product_a = Enum.slice(product, 0, 10)
    IO.inspect(head_a, label: "header length")
    IO.inspect(product_a, label: "product length")
    params = Map.new(List.zip([head_a, product_a]))
    IO.inspect(params,label: "params_new")
    changeset = Ecto.Changeset.cast(%Mirror.Imports.Product{}, params, []) # <-- problem this line
    IO.inspect(changeset, label: "changeset_new")
    product_new = Ecto.build_assoc(importer, :products, changeset)
    Repo.insert!(product_new)
  end
```

I found changeset in the above marked line contain no fields. The fourth parameter `[]` means no permitted fields allowed to be changed, not all fields are permitted.

How to set all fields permitted simply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can use [`Ecto.Schema`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#module-reflection) reflection as `__schema__(:fields)`.

```elixir
%Mirror.Imports.Product{}
|> Ecto.Changeset.cast(params, __schema__(:fields))
```